# How to configure PhpUnit in Xampp?

Tags: php, installation, phpunit, xampp

I have successfully installed PhpUnit in Xampp, now I need to configure it, i need to take this steps from the documentation:

```
2. Prepare the phpunit script:
   1.
      Rename the phpunit.php script to phpunit.
   2.
      Replace the @php_bin@ string in it with the path to your PHP command-line interpreter (usually /usr/bin/php).
   3.
      Copy it to a directory that is in your path and make it executable (chmod +x phpunit).


3. Prepare the PHPUnit/Util/PHP.php script:
   1.
      Replace the @php_bin@ string in it with the path to your PHP command-line interpreter (usually /usr/bin/php).
```

I can't find phpunit.php in the PEAR directory. Any clues on where is this file on a Xampp installation of PhpUnit? Any clues?

Best Regards,

---

Update1:

I have install it via PEAR. Ok, I will see if that work.

Best Regards,

Comment: From your other questions i figure it worked ? Or did you run into another problem ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install it ? If you use the pear installer that is shipped with Xampp it should just work.

```
/opt/lampp/bin/pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
/opt/lampp/bin/pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

and the executable should then reside in /opt/lampp/bin/phpunit.

If you installed it in another way (coping the files ?, sry i didn't find other hints in the xampp docs) then just point me to it and i will edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make a **summary** of all **necessary / useful commands** to install phpunit. I hope this still might help some people, who stumble upon this.

Note that it is best, to **run all commands as administrator.**

```
php go-pear.phar
pear clear-cache 
pear update-channels
pear upgrade --alldeps -f 
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear config-set preferred_state beta
pear install --onlyreqdeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Good Luck,
Sunny