# Update PHPunit Xampp

Tags: php, windows, xampp, phpunit, updates

This morning, I realized that the version of PHPUnit supplied with Xampp has been deprecated for quite a while...
.
The version 3.7.21. installed in Xampp, but the actual version (at the time of this writing) is 6.0.13.

I tried some solution proposed on google (all old 5 years + solution), including

- https://wehuberconsultingllc.com/wordpress/2007/08/18/updating-phpunit-on-xampp/
- [How to configure PhpUnit in Xampp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625218/how-to-configure-phpunit-in-xampp)
- http://www.righthandedmonkey.com/2012/09/setting-up-phpunit-with-xampp.html
- http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/7346/installing-phpunit-on-windows-xampp/p1
- ...

In any case, pear doesn't seem a viable solution. Is there a simple way to update PHPUnit in Xampp?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Actually, it can be updated in three simple steps:

1. Download the last version of PHPUnit here:
   https://phpunit.de/index.html
2. Copy “*phpunit.phar*” in “*C:\xampp\php*”.
3. In the file: “*phpunit.bat*”, update the following line:
   `"%PHPBIN%" "C:\xampp\php\phpunit" %*` to : `"%PHPBIN%" "C:\xampp\php\phpunit.phar" %`*

You don't need to restart apache.

**Additional note**: In your tests, you will need to replace: `phpunit_framework_testcase` by: `TestCase`

And include: `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` at the top of your test files.

[image: PHPunit in windows CMD]

Of course, the test suites are still compatible on my production server (centos7, follow the official documentation to update on Linux https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html).

[image: PHPUnit in Linux CMD]

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm assuming in step 3 you meant to edit `phpunit.bat` rather than `phpdoc.bat`.

Comment: Thanks for your post. It works for me. In the point 3, it should be “phpunit.bat” instead of “phpunit.bat.bat”.

Comment: @Frank Liu Fixed. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Working OK with XAMPP v7.3.7

The latest phpunit.phar can be downloaded from: https://phar.phpunit.de

- XAMPP Included Version = PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.
- DOWNLOADED Version (2019-08-11) = PHPUnit 8.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and found different solution.
I have install phpunit with composer globaly

```
composer global require phpunit/phpunit "^9"
```

and localy in my project (both same version "^9").

```
cd C:/fullpath/to/myproject

composer require-dev phpunit/phpunit "^9"
```

However for some reason phpunit was triggered from the xampp folder.. so what I did was removed

```
phpunit
phpunit.bat
```

From `C:\xampp\php` and it worked for me.

Just remember to set composer path to your env path in Windows.

Now you can create phpunit.xml in you project root (here is what worked for me):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.0/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         testdox="true"
         verbose="false"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         forceCoversAnnotation="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnError="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         stopOnIncomplete="false"
         stopOnSkipped="false"
         stopOnRisky="false">
         
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="default">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Then just cd to my root and run `phpunit` in my terminal to run all my tests from the `tests` folder

Hope you will find this information helpfull
[image]
*Editor: Hypper.js - using Git Bash on Windows 10 (incase you wonder)